# How to load kmdf driver (wfp/inspect) on system boot

Tags: windows, kmdf

I wrote simple 64bit kmdf driver (wfp/inspect). This driver is located in:

%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Inspect.sys

I can load this driver using: net start inspect.

Now I would like to load this driver during Windows startup, so I have prepared this inf file:

[Version]
    Signature   = "$Windows NT$"
    Class       = WFPCALLOUTS
    ClassGuid   = {57465043-616C-6C6F-7574-5F636C617373}
    Provider    = %ProviderString%
    CatalogFile = Inspect.cat
    DriverVer = 09/20/2018,19.58.54.237

[SourceDisksNames]
   1 = %InspectDisk%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]
   Inspect.sys = 1,,

[DestinationDirs]
    DefaultDestDir      = 12                                               ; %WinDir%\System32\Drivers
    Inspect.DriverFiles = 12                                               ; %WinDir%\System32\Drivers

[DefaultInstall]
    OptionDesc = %InspectServiceDesc%
    CopyFiles  = Inspect.DriverFiles

[DefaultInstall.Services]
    AddService = %InspectServiceName%,,Inspect.Service

[DefaultUninstall]
    DelFiles = Inspect.DriverFiles

[DefaultUninstall.Services]
    DelService = %InspectServiceName%,0x200                                ; SPSVCINST_STOPSERVICE
    DelReg     = Inspect.DelRegistry

[Inspect.DriverFiles]
    Inspect.sys,,,0x00000040                                               ; COPYFLG_OVERWRITE_OLDER_ONLY

[Inspect.Service]
    DisplayName   = %InspectServiceName%
    Description   = %InspectServiceDesc%
    ServiceType   = 1                                                      ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
    StartType     = 0                                                      ; SERVICE_BOOT_START
    ErrorControl  = 1                                                      ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
    ServiceBinary = %12%\Inspect.sys                                       ; %WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Inspect.sys 
    AddReg        = Inspect.AddRegistry

[Inspect.AddRegistry]
    HKR,"Parameters","BlockTraffic",0x00010001,"0"                         ; FLG_ADDREG_TYPE_DWORD
    HKR,"Parameters","RemoteAddressToInspect",0x00000000,"10.0.0.1"        ; FLG_ADDREG_TYPE_SZ

[Inspect.DelRegistry]
    HKR,"Parameters",,,

[Strings]
    ProviderString     = "TODO-Set-Provider"
    InspectDisk        = "Traffic Inspect Installation Disk"
    InspectServiceDesc = "Traffic Inspect Callout Driver"
    InspectServiceName = "Inspect"

but driver isn't load on boot.

As I mentioned on the begin, it's 64bit kmdf driver.

Did I forgot about something? Any suggestion/hint where the problem is?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

see the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828663/how-do-i-install-a-custom-windows-driver). TL;DR:

> Use sc create [service name] binPath= [path to your .sys file] type=
>   kernel to create a kernel-mode service and sc start [service name] to
>   start it